# Chef Vault - deleting vault item produces 'data bag #{VAULT} is not a vault' error

Tags: chef-infra, knife, chef-vault

I keep having a persistent error where a vault becomes a data bag after removing a vault item.

The commands run to produce this error are `knife vault delete VAULT ITEM` and then `knife vault show VAULT`.

Once the delete has been performed it is irreversible and re-adding that previously added vault item doesn't fix the issue.

Has anyone come across this and if so, how was it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

All vault items are data bag items (well, two data bag items). Check where the specific error is coming from in the code and use that to see what it thinks is failing. It might be incorrectly removing things from the `_keys` bag for the item.

Comment: After deleting it, there is no trace of the delete item in the vault or data bag.